# How to show comma in a disabled input field that belongs to a formArray?

Tags: angular

We used this method of showing an amount/figure with a comma saved from the db to a disabled textfield.

This is the .html:

```
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="test" [value]="type.get('test').value | number : '1.2-2'">
```

and this is the .ts:

```
this.type.controls['test'].setValue('1000000');
```

so the output would be: 1,000,000

But my problem now is I have a disabled textfield inside a formArray, and I couldn't get the method to work for this textfield.

my .html:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                <input 
                                  matInput 
                                  placeholder="Total Program Funding Needs" 
                                  id="program_funding_needs" 
                                  name="program_funding_needs" 
                                  formControlName="program_funding_needs" 
                                  [value]="getAdvocaciesPrograms.get('program_funding_needs[i]')?.value | number : '1.2-2'" >
                              </mat-form-field>
```

my .ts:

```
const programDetails = <FormArray>this.type.controls['advocaciesPrograms'];
programDetails.controls[i].get('program_duration').setValue(program.duration);
programDetails.controls[i].get('program_location').setValue(program.location);
programDetails.controls[i].get('program_funding_needs').setValue(program.funding_needs);
```

and my output: 1000000

Hoping I could get some kind of help, thanks!

P.S
Here's a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwryz5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @Rajat I have added a stackBlitz link. I hope it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem of getting the control reference here `('program_funding_needs[i]')`, can be solve like this e

```html
<div class="sections" formArrayName="sections" 
     *ngFor="let section of getSections.controls; let i = index;">
  <fieldset [formGroupName] = "i">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      formControlName="field1"
      [value]="getSections.controls[i].get('field1').value | number: '1.2-2'"
    >
      <button (click)="fetchAmount(i)">Show</button>
      <button (click)="removeSection(i)">Delete Section</button>
  </fieldset>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egd3fh)

but becuase you already got the reference of the formgroup by 'section' variable can be access like this

```html
 <input 
      type="text" 
      formControlName="field1"
      [value]="section.get('field1').value | number: '1.2-2'"
    >
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It definitely worked. Stay safe, friend!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the input value directive to `[value]="section.value.field1 | number: '1.2-2'"`. Good luck!

Comment: I was adding this section to my answer  but you was faster than me 

Comment: Haha, well actually I think your addition is better practice tho (i.e. using the `get` method to retrieve the value)